# Puppet - Split - Get last element of variable size array

Tags: puppet

Anyone know a clever way to get the last element of an array within a puppet manifest?

Existing code looks like:

```
class nginx {

    define vhost {

        #-----
        # Init vars
        #-----
        $app_parts = split($name, '[_]')

        # I can access any element using numeric notation
        notify { "Element: ${app_parts[0]}": }

        # How do I access the last element?
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> ```
> Arrays support negative indexing, with -1 being the final element of the array:
> ```

[Link to documentation](https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/latest/lang_data_array.html#accessing-sections-of-an-array)

so..

```
$foo = [ 'one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five' ]
notice( $foo[-1] )
# 'five'
```

Comment: Ugh, I should have guessed that one. This worked, thanks!

Comment: S'ok.  I had to test the theory out in IRB, anyway, then went off googling.